# ubuntu 12.04 dhcp gateway server

Tags: 12.04, networking, dhcp, gateway

I need a little help. I will explain this the best I can so people don't have to ask extra questions.

Essentially, I have a dell poweredge 2650, with 2 nics. eth0 goes to my cable modem, while eth1 goes to a dell powerconnect 3348.

I have installed isc-dhcp-server on my machine also. The goal is for this box to be my dhcp server and my gateway to the magical internet.

Here is my set up for /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.1.0
mtu 1392
```

I added the mtu in when I was trouble shooting.

- when I type in ifconfig, eth0 has the external address from my comcast cable modem. eth1 is set to 10.0.1.1 like i asked.
- When I connect things to the server via the switch/ethernet, an ip address gets assigned between 10.0.1.150 - 10.0.1.199 without any problems
- When I try to do anything from my gateway, apt-get update/install it connects and works no problem.
- When I try apt-get from my other boxes, its super slow, like 1% a min or slower. I can't access internet pages via my macbook or hp laptop.

However I can ping and traceroute not problem.

via mac terminal `ping -s 549 google.com` does not work and gets a time out error but `ping -s 548 google.com` works fine.

I have no idea why this would be happening and I can't find anything around other then the mtu stuff which I don't understand.

Let me know if you have any questions or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to bridge the 2 Ethernet ports? [How do I setup DHCP-Server interfaces so they are mapped/bridged to each other?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70339/how-do-i-setup-dhcp-server-interfaces-so-they-are-mapped-bridged-to-each-other?rq=1)
There's a simple guide there.